# replace multiple words in string with specific words from list

Tags: powerquery, m

How can I, using M-language, replace specific words in a string with other specific words that are specified in a table?

See my example data:

[image]

Source code:

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromColumns({{"aa &bb &cc dd","&ee ff &gg hh &ii"}, {Table.FromColumns({{"&bb","&cc"}, {"ReplacementForbb", "ccReplacement"}},{"StringToFind", "ReplaceWith"}), Table.FromColumns({{"&ee", "&gg","&ii"}, {"OtherReplacementForee", "SomeReplacementForgg", "Replacingii"}},{"StringToFind", "ReplaceWith"})}, {"aa ReplacementForbb ccReplacement dd","OtherReplacementForee ff SomeReplacementForgg hh Replacingii"}},{"OriginalString", "Replacements", "WantedResult"})
in
    someTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a neat question. You can do this with some table and list M functions as a custom column like this:

```
= Text.Combine(
      List.ReplaceMatchingItems(
          Text.Split([OriginalString], " "),
          List.Transform(Table.ToList([Replacements]),
              each Text.Split(_,",")
          )
      ),
  " ")
```

I'll walk through how this works using the first row as an example.

---

The `[OriginalString]` is `"aa &bb &cc dd"` and we use `Text.Split`  to convert it to a list.

```
"aa &bb &cc dd" --Text.Split--> {"aa", "&bb", "&cc", "dd"}
```

Now we need to work on the `[Replacements]` table and convert it into a list of lists. It starts out:

```
StringToFind  ReplaceWith
------------------------------
&bb           ReplacementForbb
&bb           ccReplacement
```

Using `Table.ToList` this becomes a two element list (since the table had two rows).

```
{"&bb,ReplacementForbb","&cc,ccReplacement"}
```

Using `Text.Split` on the comma, we can transform each element into a list to get

```
{{"&bb","ReplacementForbb"},{"&cc","ccReplacement"}}
```

which is the form we need for the `List.ReplaceMatchingItems` function.

```
List.ReplaceMatchingItems(
    {"aa", "&bb", "&cc", "dd"},
    {{"&bb","ReplacementForbb"},{"&cc","ccReplacement"}}
)
```

This does the replacement and returns the list

```
{"aa","ReplacementForbb","ccReplacement","dd"}
```

Finally, we use `Text.Combine` to concatenate the list above into a single string.

```
"aa ReplacementForbb ccReplacement dd"
```

Comment: very nice! I was thinking there was some "Text.ReplaceMatchingItems" thing, but your way to convert the string into a list, use ReplaceMatchingItems on it, and converting the list back into a string, is something I would not have thought about. 
Though, I think it's strange such a Text function does not exist...

Comment: A text function would have to deal with possible overlapping matches where the order of replacement would make a difference. It makes sense to me why they wouldn't want to implement something like that.

Comment: Alexis, I have tried to implement your solution in my real data, but I made some wrong assumptions in my original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457300/extract-and-replace-parameters-in-sql-query-using-m-language for my new (related) question...