# How to replace more values in one column

Tags: powerquery, m

I am trying to replace 3 values in one column, but I would like to do it in one step instead of three steps. I don't want to have Replaced Value1, Replaces Value2 and Replaced Value 3.

Imagine you have in column Cars only these values: Volkswagen, Renault and Dacia. You want to replace them like:

```
Volkswagen --> VW
Renault --> RN
Dacia --> DC
```

Is it possible to do it in one step instead of 3? I am trying to use statement `Table.ReplaceValue`

Many thanks

Comment: Similar question: [replace multiple words in string with specific words from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401498/replace-multiple-words-in-string-with-specific-words-from-list/54406959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @Aleksei's answer, you can use the `Table.ReplaceValue` function instead if you prefer:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(YourTable, each [Car], each RenameCars{[Name = [Car]]}[Name_mod], Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Car"})
```

This assumes you have the `RenameCars` table as well.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods is creating **RenameCars** table like this:

[image]

After adding this table to PQ you may use following formula:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(YourTable, {"Cars", each
                         try RenameCars{[Name = _]}[Name_mod] otherwise _})
```

Another way (if your list of replacements is quite short) is using **Record.FieldOrDefault** function. In this case supporting table is not needed.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(YourTable, {"Cars", each
            Record.FieldOrDefault([Volkswagen = "VW", Renault = "RN", Dacia = "DC"],_,_)})
```

Comment: thank you, I wanted to code it, but this is faster and much easier